# Facebook App dashboard Open Graph tab not available

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

I just created my application on Facebook Developers, but when I click the Open Graph tab on the dashboard it answers with "Page not found".

Did I skip a step? How can I access this tab and start configuring Open Graph objects/actions ?

Thanks

Comment: I experience it sometimes. If I restart the browser everything works fine. But this does not look like a question.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't help.. I tried deleting the app and creating it again, no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Weird this shouldn't happen. Can you open a bug against facebook? https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Yes I finally found out how to do that.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/222155087887021